# Unable to use redux on drawer in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am successfully able to connect redux while using react-native-navigation. But I am getting an error while connecting redux to drawer component. I am using Navigation.startSingleScreenApp.

Here is the error:

> Cannot read property 'navigatorStyle' of undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at "[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and adjust your question accordingly. Currently you've no improvable code posted. Thanks!

Comment: Try this 
 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigator.setStyle({
      navBarBackgroundColor: 'blue',
      navBarHidden : true,
    });
  }

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dhanunjay Kumar. This is not the working either.